# How to wait for LottieAnimationView to finish then do something

Tags: xamarin.android

I have the following code in Xamarin.Android, I want to show my main actcivty after the LottieAnimationView finshed.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/SplashAnimationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_fileName="LoadingLottie.json"
    app:lottie_loop="false"
    app:lottie_speed="1.00"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an AnimationEnd event in it. So you can try the following code:

```
LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView = this.FindViewById<LottieAnimationView>(Resource.Id.SplashAnimationView);
        lottieAnimationView.Animation.AnimationEnd += (s, e) =>
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
```